# Is it possible to rotate images in Preview in degrees other than 90?

Tags: preview

I want to rotate an image in preview but I only need to move it a few degrees.  Is this possible?  Or can you only rotate 90 degrees?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Unfortunately, Preview can only rotate in 90* increments and flip images.

If you want to rotate a different amount, you'll have to use a more-powerful program, like Photoshop or [Pixelmator](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pixelmator/id407963104?mt=12).

From Preview Help:
[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Ended up using Gimp.  Was just hoping it was possible without having to open up a whole new program.

Comment: Use Apple's Photos app. Select the Crop editing option and the degrees will show on the right side of the image. Drag your mouse on the degrees to rotate the image.

Answer (score 160):

If you're not averse to using the command line, you can use the sips command to rotate images. For example:
a) to rotate the image *destructively* where the rotated output **overwrites** the input graphical image:

```
sips -r 23 --padColor FFFFFF image.jpg
```

…will rotate image.jpg 23 degrees clockwise and "fill in" the empty space with white. (If you rotate PNGs, the alpha channel should be retained.)

b) to take and rotate image input and generate a new output image

```
sips -r 23 --padColor FFFFFF image.jpg -o output.png
```

Worth reading [the man page for sips](http://mirror.informatimago.com/next/developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sips.1.html) as it can do other useful stuff.

Answer (score 55):

There is a way to do it using Preview, although it is imprecise.

You can use a two finger twisting gesture to arbitrarily rotate the image within preview. Now, it snaps back to normal once you let go, but if you take a screenshot to clipboard while maintaining the rotated view, then paste from the clipboard into preview, then save. Then I open the image again and do a little bit of cropping to get it looking nice.

I mapped the 'screenshot to clipboard' function to a key combination that was easy to hit while maintaining my twist.

Obviously a dedicated app will do the job better, but I thought it was worth mentioning my OS only workaround which I discovered.

Comment: Wow maybe someone at apple read this because it is now a (somewhat hidden) feature in preview. Simply cut and paste an image and you can use the two finger twisting gesture to rotate the image.

Comment: Interesting workaround! Note that you will get a poor quality resulting image though. Real image editors will perform a high quality resampling. This method is just a crude rotation since it is "real time".

Answer (score 11):

I love the free `ToyViewer.app` (check Mac App Store). Can do some cool things with images. Small and fast.

[image]

Comment: Now on the Mac App Store, still free: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/toyviewer/id414298354?mt=12

Comment: the given link in the answer does not work

Comment: This app quite nice. Only 13mb download size

Comment: Tried this out: Does not show the rotated image while rotating it, so essentially useless.

Answer (score 7):

Copy-paste the image into another image or new file (cmd+N)
and twist the pasted object with two fingers.

(as shown here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UvE2DHJOTCE)

Comment: the youtube link is missing nowadays...

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: @user242399 The video is private in YouTube.

Answer (score 3):

In Yosemite, open the image in Photos and crop it - this function brings up a grid and alignment tool, you can then save the image simply aligned, but not necessarily cropped.

Comment: The OP is asking how to do this in Preview.

Answer (score 3):

There's no current way to do that with Preview, although you can use ImageMagick's `convert` command to do it:

```
convert your_input_image_name.png -rotate X new_output_image_name_path.png
```

This command will rotate your image X degrees, accepting a positive or negative value.

Finally, you'll probably want to remove the white background:

```
convert rotated_image_name_path.png -transparent white final_output_image_name_path.png
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to do this by copying or opening the object in a separated window, then there you can rotate it. Next, just copy back the object already at the desired position. This is the only way I've found, and works for quick tasks.

Answer (score 2):

In Preview, yes...!  I just discovered.  Hold the option button down, and use 2 fingers on the trackpad.  So many hidden features.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! I don't think your answer is correct; holding down the option button doesn't make a difference (for me at least). Please read the other answers.

Comment: @Glorfindel This just worked for me. I held the option key and used 2 fingers to rotate on the trackpad.

Comment: holding option + two fingers on track pad just creates a duplicate photo for me on mojava 10.14.6

Comment: Did not help.  As soon as I release fingers from trackpad, the image reverts to it's original position before I rotated it.  The option key did not matter either way.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, it used to be possible by holding down the option key while rotating (using the button on the toolbar), at least according to this forum entry from 2005:

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2005012115382953

But it didn't work for me on OS X Mountain Lion, all the option button did was change the rotation direction (for the rotation button on the toolbar).

Answer (score 1):

I found an online website that does it (probably there are many others):

- LunaPic (http://www140.lunapic.com/editor/)

No need to register or install anything. Just upload the picture, type how many degrees should be rotated and done.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this straight from Preview if you're on a MacBook. Just put two fingers on the touch pad, rotate, and viola. Unfortunately, there is no way to input exactly the degrees to which you want to rotate, but this at least allows for an approximation.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Strange, when I do that it jumps and snaps into 90degrees positions

Answer (score 1):

If you have a trackpad, visit System Preferences > Trackpad panel and select Rotate in the Scroll & Zoom tab. Now, once in Preview, you can rotate your image by the amount you prefer, by using your thumb and index finger in a rotating manner on the trackpad. No need to click on the trackpad or hold down the option key. Without a trackpad, Preview only offers 90-degree rotational increments.